# c# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException error in windbg

Tags: c#, com, windbg

I am new to C#.

I am writing a software which uses com objects from  a 3rd party.

While in visual studio it runs fine, when I try on  another machine (I copied all the source files into it) the application crashes at startup with "  Problem Event Name:  CLR20r3".

After searching I found out windbg, I tried to debug and came up with the results below;

At the end you can see, System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException.
I searched with the error code but could not come up with any results.
Can anyone help me about what the problem can be or direct me how I can go into the details of this problem with windbg?

```
ModLoad: 76d70000 76df3000   C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
    ModLoad: 76c10000 76c9f000   C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
    (724.638): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
    (724.638): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
    ModLoad: 74b30000 74b39000   C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
    ModLoad: 5e180000 5e22a000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll
    (724.638): CLR exception - code e0434352 (!!! second chance !!!)
    eax=0017ee5c ebx=00000005 ecx=00000005 edx=00000000 esi=0017ef08 edi=00317b00
    eip=758eb760 esp=0017ee5c ebp=0017eeac iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
    cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000206
    KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x58:
    758eb760 c9              leave
    0:000> .loadby sos clr
    0:000> !CLRStack
    OS Thread Id: 0x638 (0)
    Child SP IP       Call Site
    0017efd0 758eb760 [HelperMethodFrame: 0017efd0] 
    0017f020 002d00fc checkAtmModules.Form1..ctor()*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for checkAtmModules.exe
     [C:\Users\SD\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\checkAtmModules\checkAtmModules\Form1.cs @ 20]
    0017f030 002d00a6 checkAtmModules.Program.Main() [C:\Users\SD\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\checkAtmModules\checkAtmModules\Program.cs @ 18]
    0017f268 5d3e21db [GCFrame: 0017f268] 
    0:000> !threads
    ThreadCount:      2
    UnstartedThread:  0
    BackgroundThread: 1
    PendingThread:    0
    DeadThread:       0
    Hosted Runtime:   no
                                       PreEmptive   GC Alloc                Lock
           ID  OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC           Context       Domain   Count APT Exception
       0    1   638 00317b00      6020 Enabled  01eb7ef0:01eb7fe8 003112a0     0 STA System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (01e9d454)
       2    2  13d4 00351750      b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 003112a0     0 MTA (Finalizer)
```

Comment: This is an entirely normal mishap.  The *real* problem is that you don't know enough about what went wrong.  Ensuring a program runs reliably and gives a good diagnostic when it fails on other machines is the other 90% of the project.  Subscribing the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event is never really optional.

Comment: @HansPassant: obviously he can reproduce it. The unhandled exception handler can hardly give more information than a crash dump of the situation.

Comment: Copying files to a target machine is not sufficient in many cases. That's why programs have installers. COM objects need to be registered before they can be used. Try `regsvr32` on all your DLLs and make sure you have all the dependencies installed (e.g. C runtimes).

Answer (score 0):

Before going deep into WinDBG try to create a Crash report using DebugDiag (http://debugdiag.com), it will give you information from the dump in a more friendly form.
In WinDBG you can try `!PrintException` to get more info about managed exception or `kb` command to see unmanaged stack. In MEX Debugging Extension for WinDbg you can find a `!ClrStack2` command. In SOSEX extension there is an `!mk` command that shows both managed and unmanaged stack frames.

But most probably your (3-d party) COM is improperly installed. I'd use Fuslogvw.exe and\or procmon.exe to monitor what you application was doing before the exception occurs or simply install your COM on a new machine using proper installer.